# Including 'cat' => $cat breaks meta_query

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

so, i have a custom loop that seems to be working everywhere but one place.

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'meta_key' => 'wpcf-post-weight', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num title', 
    'meta_query' => 
       array( 
            array(
                'key' => 'wpcf-featured',
                'value' => -1,
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'wpcf-news-expire-date',
                'value' => $today,
                'compare' => '>=',
            ),
       ), 
    /*'cat'=> '8',*/ 
    'posts_per_page' => 1 
);
$alertloop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

with the cat=>8 commented out, the query vars look like this

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => post
    [meta_key] => wpcf-post-weight
    [orderby] => meta_value_num title
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => wpcf-featured
                    [value] => -1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => wpcf-news-expire-date
                    [value] => 1383047207
                    [compare] => >=
                )

        )

    [posts_per_page] => 1
    [error] => 
    [m] => 
    [p] => 0
    [post_parent] =>
```

However, as soon as I uncomment the cat=>8, it's dropping the first meta_query.

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => post
    [meta_key] => wpcf-post-weight
    [orderby] => meta_value_num title
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => wpcf-news-expire-date
                    [value] => 1383046582
                    [compare] => >=
                )

        )

    [cat] => 8
    [posts_per_page] => 1
    [error] => 
    [m] =>
```

This is in Wordpress 3.7. I don't think it makes a difference, but I tried rearranging the $args order, all to no avail.
Any insight would be most appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: please don't expect people to scroll to read your code

Comment: not sure why you are using `array_merge` during your `meta_query`

Comment: I've never seen `array_merge` for a `meta_query`, you definitely should change that to `array`.

Comment: removing the array_merge doesn't change anything. Not sure how it ended up there myself. :| Thanks though.

Comment: The problem is your query doesn't look wrong to me. What about removing the unnecessary commas `'compare' => '>='` and putting the value into quotes `'value' => '-1'`.

Comment: @ialocin unfortunately, this did not solve the problem.

Comment: I cannot duplicate this issue. Your code does not behave for me the way you describe its behavior for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this works, where the other query was failing. I'm not sure if it's a bug that others are experiencing or not. Anytime I included any category "inclusive" arg, it broke my meta_query, but it didn't seem to if i was "excluding" categories. So,...making an array of all category ids, then unsetting the categories I wanted to "include" in the query. Then set array as the 'category__not_in' arg seems to be working.

I'd still love any kind of insight as to why this is happening. Thank you.

```
$cats = get_all_category_ids();
$removeKeys = array(8,10,11,12);
foreach($removeKeys as $key) {
    if (in_array($key, $cats))
    {
       unset($cats[array_search($key, $cats)]);
    }
}
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'meta_query' => 
        array( 
            array(
                'key' => 'wpcf-featured',
                'value' => -1,
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'wpcf-news-expire-date',
                'value' => $today,'compare' => '>=',
            ),
        ), 
    'category__not_in'=> $cats, 
    'posts_per_page' => 1 
);
$alertloop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: At least you got it working, unfortunately I still have no clue why using `cat` would have the effect you are describing, otherwise I'd have told you before. Building the array seems kind of ugly and unnecessary. Maybe someone else can provide an explanation, why this would be necessary. But one more thing, have you tried `category_name`?

Comment: I understand quite a few people could not replicate the problem, however, Wordpress just released a quick bugfix update that seems to have to do with this issue, so I am, of course, going to update and see if it alleviates the issue. @ialocin I did try `category_name`, as well as `category__in`. It was very odd. It seems the only way I could get it to work was to use the `category__not_in` which was exactly the opposite of what I wanted. This is why building the array of all categories, then removing the categories I wanted to include was necessary. Kind of had to work backward. Thank you all.